# Tagging pages in facebook sharing - iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I'm working with Facebook sharing in my iOS app. I have tried searching the possibilities for tagging pages but found none. Is it possible to tag pages in Facebook sharing?

Sample Facebook pages that I'm trying to tag via Facebook SDK:

1. https://www.facebook.com/NextStepFitness
2. https://www.facebook.com/operationusa/

Below is my code:

```
  let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
  content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/")
  content.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#FeelingGood")
  content.quote = "Sample Quote"

  let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
  dialog.fromViewController = self

  dialog.shareContent = content
  dialog.delegate = self
  dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.native
  if !dialog.canShow() {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.automatic
  }
  dialog.show()
```

I'm using **Xcode9.1**, **Swift 3.2**, **iOS 10.3.3** & **iOS 11**, and **FacebookSDK 4.19.0**

Comment: You are not allowed to specify such things for the user. If the user themselve wants to tag a page inside the dialog, they can do so by just using the @ syntax they already know.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, Tx..